# How can I control keyboard repeat delay in a Tkinter root window?

Tags: python, user-interface, keyboard, tkinter, tk-toolkit

This simple application *almost* does what I want:

```
import Tkinter as Tk

def hello(x):
    print "Hello"

root = Tk.Tk()
root.bind("<Up>", hello)
root.mainloop()
```

I mash down the up arrow, it prints "Hello" over and over. However, there is a delay before this repetition begins, and the repetition rate is slower than I want. **How can I set this repeat delay to zero? How can I control the repeat interval?**

I know that other Tkinter widgets have configuration options for 'repeatdelay' and 'repeatinterval', but I can't seem to find one for a Tkinter root window.

(I'm looking in your direction, [Bryan Oakley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7432/bryan-oakley))

Comment: Doing a google search on [repeatdelay site:http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4](https://www.google.com/search?q=tkinter+repeatdelay#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=+repeatdelay+site:http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tcl.tk%2Fman%2Ftcl8.4&oq=+repeatdelay+site:http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tcl.tk%2Fman%2Ftcl8.4&gs_l=serp.3...1892959.1898850.0.1900214.8.8.0.0.0.0.506.1838.1j3j2j1j0j1.8.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.cxVH0ELY7uc&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=3709cc8b571c5c16&bpcl=35466521&biw=1280&bih=917) shows that repeatdelay belongs only to widgets, not windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not something configurable in Tk -- Tk has no control over how fast the keyboard driver sends repeated key events.

What you can do instead is have a binding on the button press and button release to set and then unset a flag. Then, you can write a function that does whatever  you want it to do, then check the flag and call itself again after whatever delay you want.

The function would look something like this:

```
def hello(x):
    global SHOULD_REPEAT
    print "hello"
    if SHOULD_REPEAT:
        root.after(10, hello) # wait 10ms then repeat
```

To do it right requires a little bit more logic, but that's the general idea.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Any idea what the `repeatdelay` and `repeatinterval` options on a Spinbox do?

Comment: @Andrew: they control how quickly a mouse button press repeats. Since a mouse doesn't send multiple button presses when you hold a mouse button down, tkinter has to support this functionality itself. It only supports it in a few widgets because repeated mouse button presses is not what usually should happen. For scrollbars and spinboxes, however, it is a useful feature.

Comment: On X11, you control the keyboard repeat parameters at the system level with the `xset` utility. Many OSes have graphical ways to set this sort of functionality too.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a complete example based on [Bryan's answer in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12995346/7032856):

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk


def step(*event):
    label['text'] += 1


    if label._repeat_on:
        root.after(label._repeat_freq, step)


def stop(*event):
    if label._repeat_on:
        label._repeat_on = False
        root.after(label._repeat_freq + 1, stop)
    else:
        label._repeat_on = True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    label = tk.Label(root, text=0)
    label._repeat_freq = 10
    label._repeat_on = True

    root.bind('<KeyPress-s>', step)
    root.bind('<KeyRelease-s>', stop)

    label.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I just need to find a way to apply it to Turtle Graphics :)

Comment: Found it! For those like me looking for a way to get fast key repeat in Turtle Graphics, have a look at the last answer in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863600/turtle-graphics-keypress-event-not-repeating