# How to speed up scrolling responsiveness when displaying lots of text

Tags: python, tkinter, render

I am trying to create a Python script to highlight specific patterns in a .txt file. To do this, I have altered a script which used Tkinter to highlight a given set of data. However, the files I tend to get it to process are around 10000 lines, which results in slow scrolling as I *think* it renders everything - whether it is on the screen or not (correct me if I'm wrong). Is it possible to alter my code such that it renders the output in a more efficient way? I have tried searching for a means to do this, but have not found anything myself.

My code is as follows:

```
from Tkinter import *

class FullScreenApp(object):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        self.master=master
        pad=3
        self._geom='200x200+0+0'
        master.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(
            master.winfo_screenwidth()-pad, master.winfo_screenheight()-pad))
        master.bind('<Escape>',self.toggle_geom)            
    def toggle_geom(self,event):
        geom=self.master.winfo_geometry()
        print(geom,self._geom)
        self.master.geometry(self._geom)
        self._geom=geom

root = Tk()
app = FullScreenApp(root)
t = Text(root)
t.pack()

#Import file
with open('data.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        t.insert(END, line)

#Search terms - Leave blank if not required       
search_term0 = '0xCAFE'
search_term1 = '0x0011'
search_term2 = '0x961E'
search_term3 = '0x0000'
search_term4 = ''

#Assigns highlighted colours for terms not blank
t.tag_config(search_term0, background='red')
if search_term1 != '':
    t.tag_config(search_term1, background='red')
if search_term2 != '':    
    t.tag_config(search_term2, background='red')
if search_term3 != '':
    t.tag_config(search_term3, background='red')
if search_term4 != '':
    t.tag_config(search_term4, background='red')

#Define search
#Requires text widget, the keyword, and a tag
def search(text_widget, keyword, tag):
    pos = '1.0'
    while True:
        idx = text_widget.search(keyword, pos, END)
        if not idx:
            break
        pos = '{}+{}c'.format(idx, len(keyword))
        text_widget.tag_add(tag, idx, pos)

#Search for terms that are not blank
search(t, search_term0, search_term0)
if search_term1 != '':
    search(t, search_term1, search_term1)
if search_term2 != '':
    search(t, search_term2, search_term2)
if search_term3 != '':
    search(t, search_term3, search_term3)
if search_term4 != '':
    search(t, search_term4, search_term3)

root.mainloop()
```

An example of the data in a file is given in the following link: [here](http://pastebin.com/vqC5viw2)

Many thanks for your time, it is really appreciated.

Comment: I've changed the title of the question to reflect what you want fixed instead of what you think is required to fix it.  Mostly because I think it would be the other way around: I'd think that rendering everything would make it really slow when first displaying it but make scrolling really fast (since it is done all the rendering already) but having to re-render every time it scrolls would slow it down.

Comment: Some of the indentation is broken in your code.

Comment: Thank you Tadhg, I am a very inexperienced programmer and probably don't realise what I really want. :)

Thanks Bryan, I think I have fixed the errors.

Comment: When I run this code on a 10,000 line file (where is line is < 100  characters long), the scrolling is extremely fast. Even with 100,000 lines, scrolling is just fine.

Comment: Maybe it is just my computer then... Whilst holding down, it slows to maybe just 2 or 3 lines per second. :/

Comment: _"whilst hold down, it slows to maybe just 2 or 3 lines per second"_ - with only the _exact_ code you posted in the question?  Also, is each line in the file long? I get maybe 40-50 lines per second.

Comment: Yes, I've copied and pasted the above code to 100% confirm it is the same code and have tried with multiple input files to check if the behaviour is consistent depending on input; it is. The lines aren't long - maybe 20 characters max. I will attach an example data file in my original post, if that is any use.

Comment: How slow/old is your computer??? Mine isn't spectacular and I don't notice any kind of sluggishness when scrolling through this data.

Comment: Not even 6 months old laptop - i5, 8GB RAM. Using Spyder python xy on win 10 if that could effect anything...

Comment: That's at least on par with mine. How are you scrolling?

Comment: Scrolling by holding the down arrow key.

Comment: I suspect you have some OS setting that's limiting that - can you scroll faster with a mousewheel?

Comment: Hi Wayne, using a mousewheel to 'drag' the output seems to move it very fast. When using the arrow keys, it starts off at a reasonable speed, but slows down  - which lead me to think it was some speed issue. However that may not be the case.

Comment: I took a [quick screencap](http://imgur.com/a/7jeN1) of my scrolling. I start off scrolling with the mousewheel, but then I change to scrolling with the arrow keys.

Comment: @T.Anserson I thought this question should get answered so I put a bounty on it

Comment: Check out my answer, I edited it; it should work now

Answer (score 1):

Assuming MCVE is the following:

```
import tkinter as tk


def create_text(text_len):
    _text = list()
    for _ in range(text_len):
        _text.append("{}\n".format(_))
    _text = "".join(_text)
    return _text


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    txt = tk.Text(root)

    txt.text = create_text(10000)
    txt.insert('end', txt.text)

    txt.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

## Analysis

Based on [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dn7AM.jpg) I don't think it is a rendering issue. I think it's an issue with having a [fixed rate of registering `<KeyPress>` events](https://superuser.com/q/1077223/810934). Meaning that the number of events registered per second is fixed, even though the hardware may be capable of registering at a faster rate. A similar regulation should be true also for the mouse-scroll event.

---

## Solutions for rendering

Perhaps slicing text for a buffer proportion of `txt['height']` would help. But isn't that how Tk supposed to be rendering anyway?

---

## Solutions for rendering unrelated issue

If a step would be defined as the cursor's movement to the previous or the next line, for every registered event of <kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Down</kbd>; then `scrolling_speed = step * event_register_frequency`.

---

**By increasing the step size**

An easy workaround would be to simply increase the step size, as in increasing the number of lines to jump, for each registration of the key bind.

But there's already such default behavior, assuming the page length > 1 line, <kbd>Page Up</kbd> or <kbd>Page Down</kbd> has a step size of a page. Which makes the scrolling speed increase, even though the event registration rate remains the same.

Alternatively, a new event handler with a greater step size may be defined to call multiple cursor movements for each registration of <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd>, such as:

```
import tkinter as tk


def create_text(text_len):
    _text = list()
    for _ in range(text_len):
        _text.append("{}\n".format(_))
    _text = "".join(_text)
    return _text


def step(event):
    if txt._step_size != 1:
        _no_of_lines_to_jump = txt._step_size
        if event.keysym == 'Up':
            _no_of_lines_to_jump *= -1

        _position = root.tk.call('tk::TextUpDownLine', txt, _no_of_lines_to_jump)
        root.tk.call('tk::TextSetCursor', txt, _position)
        return "break"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    txt = tk.Text(root)

    txt.text = create_text(10000)
    txt.insert('end', txt.text)

    txt._step_size = 12
    txt.bind("<Up>", step)
    txt.bind("<Down>", step)

    txt.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

**By mimicking keypress event registry rate increase**:

As mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12995346/7032856) actually modifying keypress registry rate is out of scope of Tk. Instead, it can be mimicked:

```
import tkinter as tk


def create_text(text_len):
    _text = list()
    for _ in range(text_len):
        _text.append("{}\n".format(_))
    _text = "".join(_text)
    return _text


def step_up(*event):
    _position = root.tk.call('tk::TextUpDownLine', txt, -1)
    root.tk.call('tk::TextSetCursor', txt, _position)

    if txt._repeat_on:
        root.after(txt._repeat_freq, step_up)
    return "break"


def step_down(*event):
    _position = root.tk.call('tk::TextUpDownLine', txt, 1)
    root.tk.call('tk::TextSetCursor', txt, _position)

    if txt._repeat_on:
        root.after(txt._repeat_freq, step_down)
    return "break"


def stop(*event):
    if txt._repeat_on:
        txt._repeat_on = False
        root.after(txt._repeat_freq + 1, stop)
    else:
        txt._repeat_on = True

if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()

    txt = tk.Text(root)

    txt.text = create_text(10000)
    txt.insert('end', txt.text)
    txt._repeat_freq = 100
    txt._repeat_on = True

    txt.bind("<KeyPress-Up>", step_up)
    txt.bind("<KeyRelease-Up>", stop)
    txt.bind("<KeyPress-Down>", step_down)
    txt.bind("<KeyRelease-Down>", stop)

    txt.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

**By both increasing step-size and mimicking registry rate increase**

```
import tkinter as tk


def create_text(text_len):
    _text = list()
    for _ in range(text_len):
        _text.append("{}\n".format(_))
    _text = "".join(_text)
    return _text


def step_up(*event):
    _no_of_lines_to_jump = -txt._step_size
    _position = root.tk.call('tk::TextUpDownLine', txt, _no_of_lines_to_jump)
    root.tk.call('tk::TextSetCursor', txt, _position)

    if txt._repeat_on:
        root.after(txt._repeat_freq, step_up)
    return "break"


def step_down(*event):
    _no_of_lines_to_jump = txt._step_size
    _position = root.tk.call('tk::TextUpDownLine', txt, _no_of_lines_to_jump)
    root.tk.call('tk::TextSetCursor', txt, _position)

    if txt._repeat_on:
        root.after(txt._repeat_freq, step_down)
    return "break"


def stop(*event):
    if txt._repeat_on:
        txt._repeat_on = False
        root.after(txt._repeat_freq + 1, stop)
    else:
        txt._repeat_on = True

if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()

    txt = tk.Text(root)

    txt.text = create_text(10000)
    txt.insert('end', txt.text)
    txt._step_size = 1
    txt._repeat_freq = 100
    txt._repeat_on = True

    txt.bind("<KeyPress-Up>", step_up)
    txt.bind("<KeyRelease-Up>", stop)
    txt.bind("<KeyPress-Down>", step_down)
    txt.bind("<KeyRelease-Down>", stop)

    txt.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It says i can give the bounty in 1 hour

Answer (score 0):

So this is solved by something called multi threading. A computer can do multiple tasks at once, otherwise, your web experience wouldn't be the same. Here is a simple function that demonstrates mulit-threading

```
from threading import Thread

def execOnDifferentThread(funct=print, params=("hello world",)):
    t = Thread(target=funct, args=params)
    t.start()
```

Now note, this might not be the best example, but all you have to do to run a function in parallel now, is `execOnDifferentThread(funct=A, params=B)` where A is a function name, and B is a **tuple**  of arguments that will be passed on  to your function. Now, I don't want to write your code for you, but using this function, you can `multi-thread` certain parts of your code to make it faster. If you are truly stuck, just comment where and ill help. But please try on your own first, now that you have the power of multi-threading on your hands

Comment: also, remember that when using global vars in multi threaded, declare them as global

Comment: I suggest threading the `t.insert` and the `search` parts of your code