# Turtle-graphics keypress event not repeating

Tags: python, events, keyboard, turtle-graphics

The following code behaves differently in different environments.

On my Windows machine (Windows 10, Python 3.6), each keypress creates a response and then nothing happens until I press a key again.

On "Python Trinkets" (https://trinket.io/python) I don't need to repeat the keypress, as holding the key down creates repeat events.

I know that the Trinket version is a JS implementation, but does that explain the difference entirely? Would the program behave the same on Linux or OS?

More importantly, is there a way to make it work on Windows so that holding a key down creates repeat events?

```
# import the turtle module so we can use all the neat code it contains
import turtle

# Create a variable `tina` that is a Turtle() object. Set shape to 'turtle'
tina = turtle.Turtle()
tina.shape('turtle')

# Create a variable `screen`, a Screen() object, that will handle keyss
screen = turtle.Screen()

# Define functions for each arrow key
def go_left():
  tina.left(7)

def go_right():
  tina.right(7)

def go_forward():
  tina.forward(10)

def go_backward():
  tina.backward(10)

# Tell the program which functions go with which keys
screen.onkey(go_left, 'Left')
screen.onkey(go_right, 'Right')
screen.onkey(go_forward, 'Up')
screen.onkey(go_backward, 'Down')

# Tell the screen to listen for key presses
screen.listen()
turtle.done()
```

Comment: You might try putting the screen.listen() in a while loop where the condition is set 'true' when the key is pressed and stays 'true' until it is released...

Comment: @Drt, what do you think `screen.listen()` does?  It only enables the window to receive events, and is usually called once per program (unless the `textinput()` and `numinput()` panels are in use.)  It's not something that stops and waits for key events nor something that can be directly disabled.

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way to make it work on Windows so that holding a key
>   down creates repeat events?

Key repeat is an operating system function and different systems handle it differently.  For example, the keys on my Apple OS X system repeat by default but I can go into System Preferences / Keyboard and change the rate and even turn it off (which I did to test the code below.)

If you don't have key repeat and want to simulate it, here's a simple example of using a turtle timer event to start a key repeating on key down and turn it off on key up:

```
# import the turtle module so we can use all the neat code it contains
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

KEY_REPEAT_RATE = 20  # in milliseconds

# Create a variable `tina` that is a Turtle() object. Set shape to 'turtle'
tina = Turtle('turtle')

# Create a variable `screen`, a Screen() object, that will handle keys
screen = Screen()

# Define functions for each arrow key
def go_left():
    tina.left(7)
    if repeating:
        screen.ontimer(go_left, KEY_REPEAT_RATE)

def go_right():
    tina.right(7)
    if repeating:
        screen.ontimer(go_right, KEY_REPEAT_RATE)

def go_forward():
    tina.forward(10)
    if repeating:
        screen.ontimer(go_forward, KEY_REPEAT_RATE)

def go_backward():
    tina.backward(10)
    if repeating:
        screen.ontimer(go_backward, KEY_REPEAT_RATE)

def start_repeat(func):
    global repeating

    repeating = True

    func()

def stop_repeat():
    global repeating

    repeating = False

repeating = False

# Tell the program which functions go with which keys
screen.onkeypress(lambda: start_repeat(go_left), 'Left')
screen.onkeyrelease(stop_repeat, 'Left')

screen.onkeypress(lambda: start_repeat(go_right), 'Right')
screen.onkeyrelease(stop_repeat, 'Right')

screen.onkeypress(lambda: start_repeat(go_forward), 'Up')
screen.onkeyrelease(stop_repeat, 'Up')

screen.onkeypress(lambda: start_repeat(go_backward), 'Down')
screen.onkeyrelease(stop_repeat, 'Down')

# Tell the screen to listen for key presses
screen.listen()

screen.mainloop()
```

However, your challenge is to figure out when you need this simulated repeat and when the system already has repeat capability -- having both active will be messy.

Comment: The thing is though that if Chrome is applying an auto-repeat then presumably it is enabled at a system level? Is there some way to make this work without modifying the Python code, beyond perhaps an initial instruction to a Screen method or some such?

Comment: @Robin, it's not clear what you're asking -- it seems you'd want to detect the state of key repeat (on, off, not implemented) from Python.  This seems like a good SO follow up question.  For the code I supplied, you can use it either way -- change the constant `True` in `start_repeat()` to a global boolean variable.  Set this variable `True` if you want simulated repeats, `False` if you don't.  The simulated repeating will never kick in if `repeating` is set to `False` in `start_repeat()`.  I believe I answered the question asked, perhaps it's time for more research and a new question.

Comment: What I trying to say is that I want the code to work "as is" without changing the body of the code. It works fine on the Trinket version. I don't want to change the code other than to possibly add a line at the top specifying the keydown behaviour. Or to find the relevant Windows setting (which doesn't sound hopeful since it's clearly already set to repeat key events since it works on Trinket.).

Comment: @cdlane: I think your understanding of how key-repeating at the OS level works with respect to keyboard event-handling in `turtle` is inaccurate. I use Windows and keys repeat by default in all other applications, but don't using `turtle`'s `screen.onkey()`…as the workaround in @Robin's own answer illustrates.

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution. I have adapted it a little to work inside my Paddle class in a Breakout game when called from a different file. It now moves smoothly across the screen with no repeat delay.  Brilliant!!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've found the solution.

The Trinket (JS) implementation is inaccurate.

Using this code: `wn.onkey(go_up, "Up")` binds the function to the key-press event in "standard" Python, which means the function is only called once.

To have it repeat while the key is held down, the following is needed:

```
def move(event):
    my_turtle.forward(5)

turtle.getcanvas().bind('<Up>', move)
```

Comment: You could use your existing `go_forward()` function by simply defining it to accept an (unused) `event` parameter. i.e. `def go_forward(event):` (or perhaps `def go_forward(_):`). Also, there's a list of recognized key names that can be used on the [manual page for Tk keysym values](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/keysyms.htm).